# Inserting each element of array associated to an ID into a database table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following array with items selected from a multiple select box.

```
array (size=2)
    0 => string 'CABLES' (length=6)
    1 => string 'PCR' (length=3)
```

I'm trying to insert these values into a table "relacionproveedorfamilia" with the following structure

```
`idProveedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idFamilia` int(11) NOT NULL
```

So for idProveedor = 1, I need to insert the array values for all the items selected.

```
idProveedor         idFamilia
1                   1
1                   2
1                   ...
```

The thing is the values from the array (CABLES, PCR, etc) are stored in a different table called "familia" in which the have a different ID number then the numbers they have in the array.

```
id         clave        description
1          PCR          ...
2          CABLES       ...
```

In my controller, I get the ID for idProveedor and the array $nombresFamilia and I call the function $relacion_proveedor

```
$idProveedor = $this->Proveedormodel->get_idConsecutivo();
$nombresFamilia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia');
$relacion_proveedor = $this->Proveedormodel->add_uk_proveedor_familia($idProveedor, $nombresFamilia);
```

This is the function I have in my model. First I get the id value from the table "familia" using the strings in the array and than I insert the value in the table "relacionproveedorfamilia".

```
function add_uk_proveedor_familia($id, $params){
    foreach($params as $clave){
        $valor = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM familia WHERE clave= '$clave'");
        $vl = mysql_fetch_array($valor);
        $familia = $vl['id'];
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO 'relacionproveedorfamilia' ('idProveedor', 'idFamilia') VALUES ('$id', '$familia')");
    }

}
```

When I try to submit the information I get the warning message:

```
Message: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
Filename: models/Proveedormodel.php
Line: $vl = mysql_fetch_array($valor);
```

Definitely the function in my model is wrong, how could I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: I saw a similar question answered that used it, should I remove it? What should I use instead?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's `$this->db` object takes care of all the database stuff for you.  You don't need to call `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
function add_uk_proveedor_familia($id, $params){
    foreach($params as $clave){
        $valor = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM familia WHERE clave= '$clave'");
        $vl = $valor->row_array();
        $familia = $vl['id'];
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO 'relacionproveedorfamilia' ('idProveedor', 'idFamilia') VALUES ('$id', '$familia')");
    }    
}
```

<sub>(See their documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html)</sub>

I *also* suggest you use their "query builder" (previously called "active record") class.  Manually inserting variables into an SQL query is just *asking* for trouble.

```
function add_uk_proveedor_familia($id, $params){
    foreach($params as $clave){
        $this->db->select('id')->from('familia')->where('clave', $clave);
        $valor = $this->db->get();

        $vl = $valor->row_array();
        $familia = $vl['id'];

        $this->db->insert('relacionproveedorfamilia', array(
            'idProveedor' => $id,
            'idFamilia' => $familia
        ));
    }    
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, and I'll keep it in mind for my future queries. Thanks!